# Elasticsearch Version 7.6 Errors when Missing Geoshape

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We have an Index that has a field of type GeoShape. If we make queries that includes this field, and the field is missing we get the error :

```
**Type: illegal_state_exception Reason: "Shape with name [34219995] found but missing geometry field"**
```

Is there any way to assign a default value to a geoshape field as one can with other types on situations when they may be null?

The query we are using is this:(using the NEST api):

```
filters.Add(fq => fq.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.LocalityId).Value(34219995)) || fq.GeoShape(g => g.Field("locationShape").Relation(GeoShapeRelation.Within).IndexedShape(f => f.Id(34219995).Index("GeoshapesIndex").Path("geometry"))));
```

If the field in the "GeoshapesIndex" is missing we get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding [`"ignore_malformed": true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html) to your field's mapping should prevent such shapes from being queried in the first place. Note that you'll have to reindex for this to take effect, though.

Secondly, try adding [`ignore_unmapped`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html#_ignore_unmapped_4) to your `geo_shape` query:

```
GET geoindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "ignore_unmapped": true,
      "polygon": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "point",
          "coordinates": [
            0.5,
            0.5
          ]
        },
        "relation": "within"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately neither helps. ignore_unmapped is for indexes that have no mapping but in our case we do have a mapping but the value is null. Also the ignore_malformed does not work either. Any other ideas. How can one stop the query throwing an exception if a geoshape field is missing. There must be a way!

Comment: What about `bool.filter.exists` before the geo query? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html If you shared your doc & mapping, it'd be easier to debug.

Comment: Not overly familiar w/ nest. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38537763/8160318